# How to configure logging.properties to throw content into a Java class (without wrapper pattern)?

Tags: java, logging

I have a common logging.properties inside my tomcat/conf directory..

how can I modify it to be able to process (with a java class) all the log generated by my application?

Is there any way to do that without using a wrapper (from Log API) class??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html) subclass to process the data being logged.

Then you can add it to your root logger via your config file or programmaticaly via the `addHandler` method of Logger class.

For example you can create a Handler subclass FoobarHandler that print all logged data on the console prefixed with a "Foobar " text:

```
public class MyHandler extends Handler {

    @Override
    public void close() throws SecurityException {
        // housekeeping before handler close
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
        // not really needed as data is processed without any sort of buffering
    }

    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord record) {
        System.out.println("Foobar " + record.getMessage().toUpperCase());
    }

}
```

In your config file you add the class name (i.e. `myapp.FoobarHandler`) of your Handler to the global handlers config:

```
# Global logging properties.
# ------------------------------------------
# The set of handlers to be loaded upon startup.
# Comma-separated list of class names.
# (? LogManager docs say no comma here, but JDK example has comma.)
handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler, myapp.FoobarHandler

# Default global logging level.
# Loggers and Handlers may override this level
.level=INFO

# Loggers
# ------------------------------------------
# Loggers are usually attached to packages.
# Here, the level for each package is specified.
# The global level is used by default, so levels
# specified here simply act as an override.
myapp.ui.level=ALL
myapp.business.level=CONFIG
myapp.data.level=SEVERE
```

Comment: could you give an example?